# UseRef stores previous value but counter of useRef works with current value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have one doubt regarding the useRef functionality. We know useEffect will update the value after render and useRef does not cause re-renders. So, value is updated one cycle late and so when we try to display any value in DOM useRef variable, it shows previous value and this becomes a major use case for useRef but then how does update count works fine and shows current value and not one cycle late?

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

function App(){

const count = useRef(0);
const text = useRef("");
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    text.current = inputValue;
    count.current = count.current + 1;
});

return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)} />
      <h1>Render Count: {count.current}</h1> //displays 1 after re-rende
      <h1>{text.current}</h1> //displays "" after re-render
    </>
  );
}
```

The count variable runs with current value and not one cycle late. Which means after I type a letter "A" in textbox, count.current becomes 1 from 0 and displays 1 but text.current displays previous value i.e "" and not "A. Why?

The count should have also run 1 cycle later and should have displayed 1 after 2nd re-render instead of 1st re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Because when the component isMounted at the first rendering, the value of `counter.current` becomes `1`, but the value of `text.current` is still `""`. If you want to make them synchronized do not increase the value of `counter.current` at the first calling of `useEffect` callback, cause there is not any changes occured in the `input` field at that time.

Define a `useRef` controlling whether the component isMounted or isUpdated like this :

```
const isMounted = useRef(false);
```

And then change the `useEffect` callback:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(isMounted.current){
    text.current = inputValue;
    count.current = count.current + 1;
  }
  else{
    isMounted.current = true;
  }
});
```

This time you can see, both of `counter.current` and `text.current` are one behind the current changes and they are synchronized together.

By the way always track an input changes with **state hook** not **ref hook**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root core is two things below:

1. Firstly, `useEffect` hook is triggered after rendering or re-rendering so the code in `useEffect` hook will be updated later
2. text.current = inputValue means it has reference to `inputValue`, so when `inputValue` has latest value, `text.current` has the new value at the same time. This process happens in `onChange` event and before `useEffect`.

It leads to `text.current` has latest value, `count.current` hasn't